# Filtrar varias palabras de búsqueda en Tweepy en Python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Estoy utilizando la librería Tweepy para realizar búsquedas en Twitter. Para ello utilizo esta sentencia en Python:

`myStream.filter(languages=['es'], track=["Madrid", "Londres"])`

Que devuelve los tweets que contengan las palabras Madrid **o** Londres. Pero yo quiero que me devuelva los tweets que contengan las palabras Madrid **y** Londres.

¿Alguien sabe cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Podrías intentarlo de forma efectiva filtrando los resultados tras la consulta, tweets = api.search("python")
 for tweet in tweets:
    if tweet.lang == "es":
       print(tweet.texto)
       # filtra por tu criterio

Comment: No es mala idea, pero tal vez menos eficiente. ¡Lo tendré en cuenta!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El [enlace a la documentacion](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters) dice que:

> A phrase may be one or more terms separated by spaces, and a phrase will match if all of the terms in the phrase are present in the Tweet, regardless of order and ignoring case. By this model, you can think of commas as logical ORs, while spaces are equivalent to logical ANDs

Traducción:

> La frase puede ser uno o más términos separados por espacio y habrá coincidencia en la búsqueda si todos los términos de la frase están presentes en el tweet (ignorando el orden y mayúsculas o minúsculas). Con este modelo, los espacios son operadores AND y las comas son operadores OR

Así que tu filtro sería:

```
myStream.filter(languages=['es'], track=["Madrid Londres"])
```

Comment: lois6b creo recordar  que funciona tal y como dices. Yo al menos no encuentro ninguna referencia a esto en la propia doc de tweepy :(, no obstante, si que se hace referencia en la propia API de Twitter en https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters (en el apartado `track` se explica este comportamiento). Te lo dejo por si consideras agregarlo. Un saludo.

Comment: @FJSevilla gracias! no lo encontraba por ningun lado ...