# Filtrar la raíz de una palabra en una búsqueda

Tags: python, twitter, nlp, tweepy

Estoy utilizando la librería Tweepy para realizar búsquedas en Twitter. Para ello utilizo esta sentencia en Python:

```
myStream.filter(languages=['es'], track=["coche"])
```

Que devuelve los tweets que contengan la palabra "coche". Pero estoy interesado en que me devuelva los tweets que contengan la raíz de la palabra. Por ejemplo: **coche**s, **coche**ra, **coche**ro, **coche**cito, etc.

He pensado en algún carácter especial o comodín del tipo coche* o coche? pero no he encontrado nada en la documentación. Enlace a la documentación de tweepy [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/109272/4883).

¿Alguien sabe cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Hasta dónde he podido leer la documentación de la API de twitter, no hay forma de hacer búsquedas por la raíz de una palabra ni siquiera usar comodines, tomando tu ejemplo: `myStream.filter(languages=['es'], track=["coch"])` solo recuperaría aquellos twits dónde figure la palabra **`coch`**. De manera que la respuesta rápida sería ***No se puede***. Sin embargo hay una alternativa que tiene sus complicaciones pero que eventualmente podrías evaluar si te sirve.

El tema es que nada te impide que puedas aplicar el filtro sobre varias palabras, nuevamente tomando tu ejemplo `myStream.filter(languages=['es'], track=["coche", "coches", "cochera", "cochero", "cochecito"])`. Teniendo esto en mente, el problema entonces pasaría en como generar listas de palabras con una misma raíz. El proceso de encontrar una raíz a una palabra se conoce como **[Stemming](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming)**. Existen varios algoritmos, esencialmente hacen lo mismo: recortar una palabra de tal forma  de reducirlas a palabras más pequeñas. Muchos de estos algoritmos no están orientados particularmente a la lengua castellana, pero el llamado **[Snowball](http://snowball.tartarus.org/)** sí funciona bastante bien con nuestra lengua.

Una aclaración importante con el ejemplo que has dado: `coches, cochera, cochero, cochecito` no tienen la misma raíz (al menos aplicando **[Snowball](http://snowball.tartarus.org/)**), eventualmente podrías programar algún algoritmo particular. Lo que sí es posible es aplicar varias veces el algoritmo sobre las mismas raíces y poder llegar a que **`coch`** sea la raíz de casi todas las palabras de tu ejemplo.

La idea básica sería poder tener una "bolsa" de raíces y palabras para que al momento de querer buscar un palabra, por ejemplo `"coche"` la "bolsa" nos retorne: `["coche", "coches", "cochera", "cochero"]` y sea esta la lista de términos que indicaremos a la API de Twitter. Esto requiere un "entrenamiento" previo, es decir, alimentar nuestra "bolsa" con todas aquellas palabras que suponemos se podrían buscar y quisiéramos encontrar. **Aquí radica el principal problema de esta solución, ¿cuáles son estas palabras? ¿Todas las de la lengua? ¿un grupo más reducido?.**

El siguiente es un código a modo de prueba de concepto, si te sirve o no, eso únicamente tu lo puedes evaluar. Trabajaremos con **[`nltk`](http://www.nltk.org/)** la librería más habitual para procesamiento de lenguaje natural.

Definiremos primero un objeto `WordStemmerBag` que será nuestra "bolsa" de raíces y palabras, con el metódo `add_words` podremos incorporar listas de palabras a nuestra "bolsa"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
import pickle

class WordStemmerBag():

    def __init__(self, lang='spanish'):
        """WordStemmerBag es una bolsa de palabras y sus raices
        La idea es que uno vaya agregando palabras y luego buscar una en particular y 
        retornara todas las que tienen raices en comun
        """
        self.st = SnowballStemmer(lang)
        self.raices = {}
        self.palabras = {}

    def add_words(self, wordlist, level=1):
        """Agrega una lista de palabaras a nuestra bolsa"""
        for w in wordlist:
            if not self.palabras.get(w):
                raiz = w
                for i in range(level):
                    raiz = self.st.stem(raiz)

                if w != raiz:
                    self.palabras[w] = raiz

        # Simplificamos a las raices mas chicas
        for i in range(level):
            for k,v in self.palabras.items():
                self.palabras[k] = self.palabras.get(v, v)

        for key, value in sorted(self.palabras.items()):
            self.raices.setdefault(value, []).append(key)


    def write(self):
        """Guardar datos con pickle"""
        pickle.dump( self.raices, open( "raices.p", "wb" ) )
        pickle.dump( self.palabras, open( "palabras.p", "wb" ) )

    def load(self):
        """cargar datos previamente salvados con pickle"""
        self.raices = pickle.load( open( "raices.p", "rb" ) )
        self.palabras = pickle.load( open( "palabras.p", "rb" ) )

    def related_words(self, word):
        """Obtener palabras con raices en comun"""
        raiz = self.palabras.get(word, word)
        return sorted(list(set(self.raices.get(self.palabras.get(word, word), [word]))), key=len, reverse=True)
```

#### ¿Cómo sería el funcionamiento?

En primer lugar, debemos "entrenar" a nuestro algoritmo con la lista de palabras de tu ejemplo, usamos dos niveles, para lograr mayor cantidad de relaciones:

```
lista_palabras = ["coche", "coches", "cochera", "cochero", "cochecito"]

wsb = WordStemmerBag()
wsb.add_words(lista_palabras, level=2)
```

Con esto ya tenemos generadas nuestras palabras y raíces, ahora lo aplicaremos a nuestro problema, veamos:

```
buscar = "coche"
print('En caso que la palabra sea "{0}" buscaremos por {1}'.format(buscar, wsb.related_words(buscar)))

> En caso que la palabra sea "coche" buscaremos por ['cochera', 'cochero', 'coches', 'coche']
```

como veras en este ejemplo, partiendo de un único término llegamos a encontrar palabras relacionadas que podríamos eventualmente usar en el filtro de la API de twitter.